# SweetAlert dropdown dynamically add items in list

Tags: jquery, json, sweetalert

I am currently using sweetalert2 to capture user's input from the dialog. I would like to use the dropdown in chaining queue dialog but I can't seem to find a way to dynamically add items in the dropdown list. Let's say I want to retrieve data from JSON format and place in the dropdown list, is there a way to do it?

```
function userInput() {
    swal.setDefaults(
        {
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
            showCancelButton: true,
            animation: true,
            progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
        }
    );

    var steps = [
        {
            text: 'Select an author to analyze the commit',
            input: 'select',
            inputOptions: {
                'SRB': 'Serbia',     // How do I dynamically set value?
                'UKR': 'Ukraine',
                'HRV': 'Croatia'
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Select multiple authors to compare their commits',
            input: 'select',
            inputOptions: {
                'SRB': 'Serbia',      // How do I dynamically set value?
                'UKR': 'Ukraine',
                'HRV': 'Croatia'
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Select a file directory to analyze all author\'s commit',
            input: 'select',
            inputOptions: {
                'SRB': 'Serbia',      // How do I dynamically set value?
                'UKR': 'Ukraine',
                'HRV': 'Croatia'
            }
        }
    ];

    swal.queue(steps).then(function(result) {
        swal.resetDefaults();
        swal({
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Success',
            text: 'Scroll down for statistics!',
            html:
                'Your selections: <pre>' +
                JSON.stringify(result) +
                '</pre>',
            confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
            showCancelButton: false
        })
    }, function() {
        swal.resetDefaults()
    })
}
```

Retrieve data in JSON format:

```
function getData(repolink) {
 readDataFromGit('https://api.github.com/repos/' + repolink + '/git/trees/master?recursive=1', function(text){
        data = JSON.parse(text);
        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
            // Retrieve v.login data!
            data = v.login;
        })
    });
}

function readDataFromGit(link, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    request.open('GET', link, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == "200") {
            callback(request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [SweetAlert2 documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-options) says, `inputOptions` parameter can be `object` or `Promise`.

To populate select items dynamically you should use promises, here's the simple example:

```js
var inputOptionsPromise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
  // get your data and pass it to resolve()
  setTimeout(function () {
    resolve({
      '#FF0000': 'Red',
      '#00FF00': 'Green',
      '#0000FF': 'Blue'
    })
  }, 2000)
})

Swal.fire({
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: inputOptionsPromise
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Notice, that SweetAlert2 will automatically show a loader until the Promise for `inputOptions` parameter will be resolved or rejected.

Comment: How can I do a $.each in the resolve to add more options ??